# sql query to show joined tables by id

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have **Table A**:

```
ID | Fname
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
3  | ccc
4  | ddd
```

and **Table B**:

```
ID | Age
1  | 50
2  | 60
8  | 70
4  | 80
```

I need to run query that show me this:

```
ID | Fname | Age
1  | aaa   | 50
2  | bbb   | 60
4  | ddd   | 80
```

need it on sql server 2008

Comment: this is a basic inner join...what have you written so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a really really simple `INNER JOIN` - try this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.FName, B.Age
FROM dbo.TableA A
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

See Jeff Atwood's [visual explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) of what the different types of JOINs in SQL are and what they do.

Comment: You just wrote exactly what I was typing. lol. Even the diagram. No point posting twice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Fname, b.Age
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
```